# C# and OpenCvSharp in yocto image

Tags: c#, opencv, yocto

I am new to the yocot project and i have a project written in c sharp that uses also opencvsharp. Now i am moving to a new hardware and i need to build my own image with yocto. Is it possible to run c# and opencvsharp on the target. I would not like to put my stuff in a recipe and then only have the binaries on my device. I would like to develop with c# abd opencsharp on my device. Is that possible?

Best wishes

I found https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Building_and_running_embedded_Linux_.NET_applications_from_first_principles. But i understood it this way that this solution compiles it during the build process and then i have only the binaries on my image afterwards.

Comment: So, if you want to write c# code on your device, why not just deploy the .net development tools?

Comment: You might these layers useful https://github.com/RDunkley/meta-dotnet-core and https://github.com/jeremy-prater/meta-dotnet.